# recover files from .gzip with Python

Tags: python, gzip, unzip

I have some .gzip archives and I want to extract all files from them.
But gzip module doesn't let me get the name of each file inside the .gzip archive and **I want to recover each file with its old name**, I don't want to re-assign a new name.

`zipFile` doesn't have this problem, and tarfile too: tarfile has also a pair of methods that works with .tar.gz, but not just for .gz archives.

I'm a bit confused, first time working with archives, can you help me please?

I'm sure that it's possible because if I can do it via gui there must be a library and method/function but maybe it's C and not Python?

EDIT:

```
...
elif tarfile.is_tarfile(i) and i.endswith('.tar.gz'):
    ...
    with tarfile.TarFile.gzopen(i, 'r') as tarredgzippedFile:
```

Then, inside `with` statement I'll use the code from gzip module, really?

Comment: What do you mean by ".gz archives"?  Do you mean .tar.gz archives?  The gzip (.gz) format is _not_ an archive format.  It only stores one compressed stream.  It does not store multiple files.  The .tar format does store multiple files, with .tar.gz being a tar archive that is compressed with gzip.

Comment: yes you're right; i made a big mistake, .gzip is not an archive, so this exaplins me the whole thing! **Last problem: check the 2EDIT** i'm going to write

Answer (score -1):

Maybe my answer is dumb, but do you **really** need to do this with Python? Maybe you can turn to usual *nix shell tools:

```
tar -xvf *.gz
```

I suppose this can be not only easier, but also faster than a Python program. You can even call this shell command from Python.

Comment: my scope was to achieve the goal by python modules